# Uncaught TypeError: topTenAux.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a college Project where I need to make a Quiz game. Now, that I'm trying to do the top ten. I'm getting an error on the second push line. The wierd thing is that the 1st one runs good. The error that I'm getting is on the following image.

```
var topTen = [];
var data = { "name": localStorage.getItem("topTenPlayer"), "points": pontos };
var topTenAux = [];
if (localStorage.getItem("topTenList") == null) {
    topTen.push(data);
} else {
    topTenAux = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("topTenList"));
    topTenAux.push(data);
}
localStorage.setItem("topTenList", JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(topTen);
```

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGesW.png)

Comment: Should `topTenAux.push` be `topTen.push`?

Comment: @Cytrine, it's working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the second `push` is not working, is due that you are overwritting it from an Array to an Object here `topTenAux = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("topTenList"));` and thus Objects don't have the push method.

Instead you can add a new key:value pair with the info you want to add
`topTenAux.new_data = data`;

And if you need that later you can call it with `console.log(topTenAux.new_data)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var topTen = [];
var data = { "name": localStorage.getItem("topTenPlayer"), "points": pontos };
var topTenAux = [];
if (localStorage.getItem("topTenList") == null) {
    topTen.push(data);
} else {
    // the error is caused by the following line.
    topTenAux = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("topTenList"));
    topTenAux.push(data);
}
localStorage.setItem("topTenList", JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(topTen);
```

See my comment in the code. You re-assign `topTenAux` so that it is no longer an array.

Answer (score 0):

In this line topTenAux is receiving an object

```
topTenAux = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("topTenList"));
```

This one is using an array method

```
topTenAux.push(data);
```

I think you wanted to push the new data instead, so use this:

```
else {
    var newData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("topTenList"));
    topTenAux.push(newData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because javascript is **weakly-type** scripting language and it allows you to assign different data types to same variable.

Firstly, `topTenAux` is declared as an empty **array**, but then you're using `topTenAux = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("topTenList"))` which can be a simple primitive type and that primitive type does not contains `push` method in its `prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `topTenAux` is not an array as you are parsing this into an Object `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("topTenList"));` You need to store the result in a new variable and push to an array